# Указатели в c++

Tags: c++

Что и почему неправильно в этих объявлениях?(объявления независимые)

```
int var; int *iptr =&ivar;

int ivar, *iptr=&ivar;

float fvar; int *iptr=&fvar;

int nums[50], *iptr=nums;

int ivar, *iptr; *iptr = &ivar;
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

int var; int *iptr =&ivar;

здесь банально - `ivar` не объявлен.

```
int ivar, *iptr=&ivar;
```

здесь разве что использование неинициализированной переменной `ivar`.

```
float fvar; int *iptr=&fvar;
```

разные типы - указатель на целое и указатель на вещественное.

```
int nums[50], *iptr=nums;
```

nums является по факту указателем, оно скомпилируется. И оно работать будет. Но видимо имеется ввиду, что здесь "разные типы".

```
int ivar, *iptr; *iptr = &ivar;
```

Здесь `*iptr` - это уже разименование. `*iptr` имеет тип целое. А пытаются присвоить адрес.

Comment: С запятой хороший учебный пример на внимательность.
   
    int ivar, *iptr=&ivar;

Мне сначала показалось что это разыменование, а не объявление.

    int nums[50], *iptr=nums;

Это неявное преобразование типов nums = &nums[0]. Но оно работает.

P.S. Не объявляйте указатели в одной строчке с не указателями в реальном коде.  Это снижает читабельность.

Comment: 2-я и 4-я строки (если они независимы) без ошибок (и в С++ и в Си). В остальных ошибки, как @KoVadim написал